# Header and footer is getting the Theme structure on web

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm trying to add a company header and footer (through js script) to all the resource files-index web pages which I have imported but somehow, it's getting the style from the Theme which I am using. There's a code for style on the index and also css referencing from the theme.

Header js I placed it after body tag, and footer I placed before the end of body tag. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please try to describe a little bit more in detail what you did, and what you want to do. It sounds like you imported a number of regular .html files into the file resources in a Domino database. Is that correct? Then you want to modify those files to have a common header and footer? Where is that design coming from, and how are you inserting it into the files?

Comment: The whole set of file resources (html, js, css, etc -- Themed Wordpress) came from a vendor, and I have imported all to the File Resource in Lotus Notes Database. 

Now everything is working out well, except that the header and the footer of the company is not (this do not came from the vendor but I have to add the script src on the head tag, after the body tag and for the footer, before the end of body tag). Both in Chrome and IE, the drop down navigation is not working as expected and in the footer, the last part of the column was moved to the next line.

Comment: Without seeing your source code it's impossible to find the cause. It's probably not a Lotus Notes issue. You have an error in your HTML or Javascript.

Comment: Hi @Roman K, here is the link:  http://www20.hdb.gov.sg/fi10/fi10221p.nsf/client/hdb/index.html

Comment: It looks OK to me, but I don't know how it should really look. When I check the Javascript console, I can see several errors `$ is not a function` in your main.js, dynamic-nav.js and others. The jQuery `$` function not defined–it's common for Wordpress to work in jQuery compatibility mode. Try to put `var $=jQuery.noConflict();` after jQuery.js is loaded.

Comment: Check out the navigation in the header. It should have drop down when hovered at about us, residential, etc.

Comment: It's a Javascript issue. Look at my previous comment about `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Comment: Will do that and let you know. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @RomanK. I noticed that those script srcs which I'm using for the header and footer are using $. These references are not from the current Lotus Notes Database but accessing other database. I read in the net that mostly for Wordpress themes, they are using jQuery and not $. Could this be the issue? Please advice.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to tell you in one of my previous comments.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. So, I should try to re-create these JS files in the File Resource and instead of using $, I should use jQuery?

Comment: I tried as you asked me to and it worked! Thank you so much! I placed the code after the JS script inside the BODY tag. The remaining problem is that part of the drop-down coming from the navigation bar cannot be seen because of the header menu of the Annual Report. I know it's a CSS issue but I'm not particularly sure where. @RomanK.

Comment: I don't see any problems with drop-down menu. Maybe you can open another question, add some screenshots, and tag it with CSS. I also added the solution as answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Accepted it already. I was able to fix it. Thank you. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put var `$=jQuery.noConflict();` after jQuery.js is loaded. jQuery included with WordPress is in compatibility mode and doesn't use `$`.